# ImageLOader Android

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I am using `Universal imageloader class` with `RoundedBitmapDisplayer` options. The `RoundedBitmapDisplayer` takes a particular value (here 1000) whose documentation is not available. Does anyone know what the value represents ?

```
private DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .cacheInMemory(true).cacheOnDisk(true).resetViewBeforeLoading(true)
        .displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(1000)).showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ico_user)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ico_user).showImageOnLoading(R.drawable.ico_user).build();
```

Comment: From where did you get the `RoundedBitmapDisplayer`, it's not part of Android SDK?

Comment: Its part of imageloader class as I mentioned